# Copy data of one file to another

Tags: c, file, unix, copy

I am trying to copy data from one file to another file in UNix using "C". The condition during the copy is 1) source file does't exit 2) source file exist but the target file doest exist. 3) if source and target both files exist then choose either to overwrite the target file or append the source file data to target file data.

The below code is working fine for the first two cases . But not working for the last case(overwrite and append). When i  execute the program and  enter the existing source file ,target file location  choose either of the options the program says the data has been appended but actually data is not either appended or overwritten.

Please tell me what to do to make the program work correctly for the last case.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 512
#define PERM 0644

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
    int infile;
    int outfile;
    int choice;
    size_t size;

    if((infile = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY,0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Source file does not exist\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if((outfile=open(argv[2],O_WRONLY,PERM))>0)

    {
        //  printf("Destination Fiel Exists , Do you wish to Overwrite or Appened destination file Data :   \n Enter 1 to overwrite or ,\n 0 to Append \n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        if(choice==1)
        {
            if((outfile=open(argv[2],O_WRONLY|O_CREAT |O_EXCL, PERM))>=0)
            {
                printf("Destination file data is overwriten by source file data \n");
                return -2;
            }
        }// end if (choice =1)

        else
        {
            if(choice==0)
            {
                if((outfile=open(argv[2],O_WRONLY |O_CREAT |O_APPEND, PERM ))>=0)
                {
                    printf("Destination file data is appended with source file data : \n");
                }
            } // end if(choice==0)

            else
            {
                printf("Entered invalid choice.: \n");
            }
            return -3;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if((outfile=open(argv[2],O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL,PERM))<0)
        {
            printf("Enter the desitination file along with source file \n");
            return -4;
        }
        else {
            printf(" Data has been copied to \t%s\n", argv[2]);
        }
    }

    while ((size=read(infile, buffer, BUFFSIZE)) > 0)
    {
        write(outfile, buffer, size);
    }

    close(infile);
    close(outfile);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   if((outfile=open(argv[2],O_WRONLY|O_CREAT |O_EXCL, PERM))>=0)
   {
        printf("Destination file data is overwriten by source file data \n");
   }

// instead use 

   if((outfile=open(argv[2],O_WRONLY|O_CREAT |O_TRUNC, PERM))>=0)
   {
        printf("Destination file data is overwriten by source file data \n");
   }
```

There are a few points i would like to point out :

1. When trying to overwrite the target file, you need to use O_TRUNC
   instead of O_EXCL. This will ensure the length of target file data
   is made to 0 and then source file is copied into it.
2. Also i have
   used switch case instead of if-else clauses to make it easier to
   read
3. When you use 'return', the control goes back to the main
   and the rest of the statements will not be executed.

You could use fread() and fwrite() to make the tasks complete faster.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
if((outfile=open(argv[2],O_WRONLY|O_CREAT |O_EXCL, PERM))>=0)
{
    printf("Destination file data is overwriten by source file data \n");
}

// instead use 

if((outfile=open(argv[2],O_WRONLY|O_CREAT |O_TRUNC, PERM))>=0)
{
    printf("Destination file data is overwriten by source file data \n");
}
```

There are a few points i would like to point out :

1) When trying to overwrite the target file, you need to use `O_TRUNC` instead of `O_EXCL`. This will ensure the length of target file data is made to 0 and then source file is copied into it.

2) Also I have used switch case instead of if-else clauses to make it easier to read.

3) When you use `return`, the control goes back to the main and the rest of the statements will not be executed. You could use `fread()` and `fwrite()` to make the tasks complete faster.